# Как можно удалить bottom, top, left, right?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно удалить значение `bottom` у элементов с `position: absolute;`. Очень часто бывает что если на большом экране указан `bottom`, а на маленьком экране мне нужно использовать `top`, то элемент растягивается от значения `bottom` до значения `top`. Не могу понять как это удалять.

Comment: bottom: auto; top: xxpx;

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный вариант решения проблем с разными разрешениями экранов на разных устройствах - использовать правило `@media`. Кратко об этом [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/media), а подробно [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/). В целом же, тема достаточно объемная. Но если вам нужно просто решить вашу задачу и не влезать в дебри, то вам достаточно написать примерно такой код:

```
// 980px - ширина, ниже которой будет действовать это правило
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) { 
   #pagewrap {
      ... // тут правила для нужного вам селектора или селекторов
   }
}

// 981px - ширина, с которой начнет действовать это правило
@media screen and (min-width: 981px) {
   #pagewrap {
      ... // тут другие правила для нужного вам селектора или селекторов
   }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но я не об этом спрашивал.

Comment: @АлександрАлексеев попробуйте тогда выразиться как-то другими словами. Потому что пока что выходит так, что вам нужно именно это

Answer (score 1):

Да перезаписывать по @media оба значения, ставить одно в нужное, а второе - в auto.

Вот только что поправил так один слайдер.

Comment: Поправил ответ - auto надо